# Как загрузить файл в redmine c помощью rest api? golang

Tags: api, golang, rest, redmine

Мне нужно создавать задачи в redmine с помощью rest api. При создании задачи я должен добавлять фото. В [Документации](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api#Attaching-files) указано что для добавления файлов нужно сначала пост запросом загрузить сами файлы, получить их токены, потом при создании задачи указать эти токены.

Я получаю файлы из формы с помощью мультипарт ридера, сохраняю локально, проверяю что файл был прочитан и отправляю пост запрос:

```
    if err != nil {
        LOG.Println(err)
        return
    }
for {
        part, err := m.NextPart()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }

        fileName := part.FileName()
        if fileName != "" {
            dst, err := os.Create("./test/" + fileName)
            if err != nil {
                LOG.Println(err)
                continue
            }
            defer dst.Close()
            n, err := io.Copy(dst, part)
            fmt.Println(n, err)

            data, err := io.ReadAll(dst)
            if err != nil {
                LOG.Println(err)
                continue
            }
            reader := bytes.NewReader(data)

            rdmURL := os.Getenv("REDMINE_URL")
            rdmKey := os.Getenv("REDMINE_KEY")
            v := url.Values{}
            v.Add("key", rdmKey)
            v.Add("filename", fileName)

            url := fmt.Sprintf("%s/uploads.json?%s", rdmURL, v.Encode())

            response, err := http.Post(url, "application/octet-stream", reader)
            if err != nil {
                LOG.Println(err)
                continue
            }
            defer response.Body.Close()
            if response.StatusCode != 201 {
                reqBody, _ := io.ReadAll(response.Body)
                LOG.Println(response.StatusCode, string(reqBody))
                continue
            }
```

В доке указано что body запроса - содержимое файла. Я пробовал в качестве тела запроса передавать part, tempFile, локальный файл, reader прочитанный из локального файла: во всех случаях статус код 201, но при этом сам файл в редмайн весит 0 байт, добавляется его иконка, но сам файл пустой. Я думаю, что проблема в body. Как правильно передать содержимое файла в body запроса?

Answer (score 0):

Вы начинаете читать `dst` до того, как заканчиваете его создавать. Закройте сразу после `io.Copy` и откройте заново:

```
            dst, err := os.Create("./test/" + fileName)
            if err != nil {
                LOG.Println(err)
                continue
            }
            defer dst.Close()
            n, err := io.Copy(dst, part)
            fmt.Println(n, err)

            dst, err := os.Open("./test/" + fileName)
            if err != nil {
                LOG.Println(err)
                continue
            }
            data, err := io.ReadAll(dst)
            if err != nil {
                LOG.Println(err)
                continue
            }
            reader := bytes.NewReader(data)
```

Но на самом деле это всё не нужно. В `request` нужно передавать любой ридер, не только из байтов. Вполне достаточно использовать сразу `part`:

```
        fileName := part.FileName()
        if fileName != "" {
            rdmURL := os.Getenv("REDMINE_URL")
            rdmKey := os.Getenv("REDMINE_KEY")
            v := url.Values{}
            v.Add("key", rdmKey)
            v.Add("filename", fileName)

            url := fmt.Sprintf("%s/uploads.json?%s", rdmURL, v.Encode())

            response, err := http.Post(url, "application/octet-stream", part)
```